# Високосный год без условий и циклов C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Как найти високосный год через линейный алгоритм(без условий и циклов)?

Возникли трудности, не понимаю алгоритм.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    /*
        1. Год делится на 400->високосный->конец
        2. Год делится на 100->не високосный->конец
        3. Год делится на 4->високосный->конец
        4. Год не високосный->конец
        5. Всё
    */

    int year, result;

    cout << "Enter year: ";
    cin >> year;




    result = year / 100;
    result = year - result;

    result = result % 4;

    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "высокосный" - от слова "высоко"?

Comment: "не понимаю алгоритм" - я тоже

Comment: У вас "древесный" алгоритм. У вас должно быть три условных оператора  if

Comment: Вам дали четкий ответ на ваш вопрос, примите его, так вы благодарите автора ответа за потраченое на ваш вопрос время. Чтоб принять, [нажмите на галочку под вопросом.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: "Без условий"? Что тогда значит "найти"? В чем выражается "нахождение"? Как должен проявиться результат работы вашей программы?

Comment: Ваш код неверен. Во-первых, он дает 4 значения - от 0 до 3 - как их трактовать? Например, для 1999 и 2000 он дает по 0 - в то время как 1999 не високосный, а 2000 - високосный.

Answer (score 8):

```
bool IsLeap(int year)
{
    return (year%400==0)||((year%4==0)&&(year%100!=0));
}
```

(Из этой [книжки](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/135380989/))

Конечно, если пугает наличие `==` и `!=`, можно переписать как

```
((400-y%400)/400)||(((4-y%4)/4)&&(year%100))
```

но это уже, с моей точки зрения, извращение...

Comment: Что вы хотите - понятнее сформулируйте. Здесь нет ни if, ни ?: - что вам не нравится? Как вы хотите? Вот функция, на входе - год, на выходе - что? Какие операторы разрешены внутри? А то непонятно, что вам надо...