# Программа не выводит данные (деление и деление с остатком не понимаю)

Tags: c++

У меня есть программа, написанная для решения разных типов задач для своей конструкции. Здесь надо найти высокосный год =1 , невысокосный = 0. Чтобы найти должно делиться на 4, но если делится на 100 то должно делится и на 400.

Не понимаю что не так (желательно не менять данную конструкцию, а изменить ее)

```
    #include <iostream>
int main()
{
    long long y;
    std::cin >> y;
    if (y % 4 != 0) {
        if (y / 100) {
            if (y / 400) std::cout << '1';
            else std::cout << '0';
        }
        else if (y / 4) std::cout << '1';
        else std::cout << '0';
    }
    else std::cout << '0';
    }
```

Comment: Ну в коде же у вас используется оператор %, почему же чёрти что пишете `if (y / 100)` и т.д.

Comment: "*Не менять, а изменить*" — это как?! Гляньте сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/896876/195342

Comment: Первое условие точно не верно. На сколько я помню, должно быть: cout << (y%4 == 0 && (y%100 ||  (y%100 == 0 && y%400 == 0) ) ) ? 1 : 0

Comment: `if (y / 100)`  вовсе не означает  "если y делится на 100"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    long long y;
    std::cin >> y;
    if (y % 4 != 0 && (y % 100 != 0 || (y % 100 == 0 && y % 400 == 0)))
        std::cout << '1';
    else std::cout << '0';
}
```

Вроде так!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((year%400==0)||((year%4==0)&&(year%100!=0))) cout << 1;
else cout << 0;
```